Calculation to convert Ammonium Bifluoride to HF acid using organic acid (Formic, Acetic, Citric, or any type of acid)
I'm working as engineer designing suitable acid to stimulation sandstone (improve permeability) unfortunately not from chemistry background.
I need a help to convert ammonium Bifluoride to HF acid which will be used to stimulate or dissolve the clays / SiO2 etc. in sandstone formation. Usually, certain QTY of ABF (ammonium Bifluoride) and HCl Acid are used to create XX% of HCl: XX% of HF acid, which I already have the calculation (hafeezabalim@outlook.com)
However, I need some help to figure out to make HF acid from other type of acid (such as organic acid, Phosponic acid etc.) in combination with ABF - let say how much formic acid (liquid) and ABF (solid) required to make solution containing 9% Formic and 2% HF? just an example- thank you.
